# How to minimize the path to traverse complete graph and find optimum start point?

Tags: pandas, csv, search, graph

Say N nodes and the weight of the paths joining some of these nodes are given to you. On average, a node is directed connected to m nodes where m is much smaller than N. I am interested in know how to select the starting point of travel given that we have to cover all the nodes and with minimum path weight sum possible. Also, N is a very large number (in between 10k-50k).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say brute force is the way to go. Given graph G = (V, E), select every vertex v ε V, find the total weight from v to all the other nodes using simple breadth first search. Start from v, go out to all of it's adjacent vertices, add the weight of all of the edges, and repeat. Repeat this and you will get the minumum.